# Multiple authentication provider for specific url - Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

In Spring security I want to use Basic authentication for urls starting with api/** LDAP Rest Authentication for urls starting with /ldap/**. The current code i have also allows ldap/** with basic authentication.

The question comes even if i use them as separate AuthenticationProviders like LdapAuthProvider and BasicAuthProvider how can i use it to point to the specific urls

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity    
    public class WebSecurityConfig {


        @Configuration
        @Order(1)
        public class BasicAuthenticationProvider extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui*", "/info", "/health").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/order/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().httpBasic().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable();
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
            }
        }

        @Configuration
        @Order(2)
        public class LdapAuthenticationProvider extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ldap/**").fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable();            
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
// auth.ldapAuthentication() code here......
            }      
        }    
    }
```

Comment: I have added the code I had tried and it also allows /ldap/** with the basic authentication which puzzles me

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, You have multiple entry points in one application and there are different types of users that can access different portions of the application.

You should look at this Baeldung tutorial: [Multiple Entry Points in Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points)